# Unable to retrieve data from the specified index of a Bluetooth device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, bluetooth

The following application reads data from a Nonin 3150 Bluetooth device by establishing connections with the COM ports.  The documentation for the device [is here](http://www.nonin.com/documents/3150-Specifications_7970-000-Rev-A.pdf).  Trying to extract only the pulse rate and SPO data.

The following process buffer method creates an array of Bytes.  How can the pointer retrieve data from the correct index (pulse rate / SPO data)?

Code:

```
try
{
    serialPort.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
    serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    serialPort.DataBits = 8;
    serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    serialPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII ;

    serialPort.Open();
    label1.Text = comboBox1.Text + " is opened";
    // textBox1.Text = 
    serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(datareceived);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}

void datareceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    myDelegate d = new myDelegate(update);
    textBox1.Invoke(d, new object[] { });
}

{
        while (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        bBuffer.Add((byte)serialPort.ReadByte());

        ProcessBuffer(bBuffer);
    }

    private void ProcessBuffer(List<byte> bBuffer)
    {
        // Look in the byte array for useful information then remove the useful data from the buffer

        // Create a byte array buffer to hold the incoming data
        byte[] buffer = bBuffer.ToArray();


        // Show the user the incoming data 
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
          textBox1.Text = bBuffer[i].ToString();
        }        

        textBox1.ScrollToCaret();        
    }
```

Comment: The key bit of data you are missing is "A frame consists of 5 bytes; a packet consists of 25 frames. Three packets (75 frames) are transmitted each second."  - You have to read the table.. figure out what frame you are in and then grab your SpO2 or beats reading.

Comment: Hi Boo, Thanks for your reply. I'm looking at the table now on pg 22, can i conclude that frame 3 is the spO2 data wherelse the beats is at frame 20/21. I would like to know how do I convert this data and display it in float format? I'm still unsure how to go about doing the conversion. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yeah, that seems correct based on what I am reading there (assuming you are using dataformat 2).  It calls it a "float" byte, but its a 7-bit byte.. which gives you a range from 0 to 127.  I'm unsure how to interpret that.  I'd read the byte in and see if it looks right to you.  Also, don't forget that Windows is a Little-Endian OS.. I'm unsure if the data you are rcv'ing is in Little or Big Endian format.

Comment: Hi Boo, I've managed to read the data using the readbytes. However, I'm unsure on how to extract the exact packet data as shown on the table.